# Yii2 kartik depend dropdown doesnt load next drop down list

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I am using kartik DepDropdown widget. When I choose the region it must load all the cities from it in the particular dropdown (e.g. the one with id `city_id`).
In the chrome network tab I can see that the action returns the expected result json format of all the cities

```
{
  "output": {
    "40": "Велико Търново",
    "41": "Горна Оряховица",
    "42": "Елена",
    "43": "Златарица",
    "44": "Лясковец",
    "45": "Павликени",
    "46": "Полски Тръмбеш",
    "47": "Свищов",
    "48": "Стражица",
    "49": "Сухиндол"
  },
  "selected": ""
}
```

But they doesn't load in the `#city_id` dropdown. My view looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">

                                <?= $form->field($model, 'region_id')->dropDownList(Region::getAllRegions(), ['id' => 'region-dd', 'prompt'=> ' - ' . Yii::t('app', 'Region') . ' - ']); ?>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">

                                <?= $form->field($model, 'city_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                                    'options'=>[
                                        'id'=>'city-id'
                                    ],
                                    'pluginOptions'=>[
                                        'allowClear' => true,
                                        'depends' => ['region-dd'],
                                        'url' => Url::to(['/system-information/load-cities'])
                                    ]
                                ]); ?>

                            </div>
```

My controller:

```
public function actionLoadCities()
    {
        $out = [];

        if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
            $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
            if ($parents != null) {
                $region_id = $parents[0];
                $out = City::getAllCities($region_id);
                echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
                return;
            }
        }
        echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the `name=>value` pairs of the `id` and the `text` to be assigned for a single option, if you look into the [**`DOCS`**](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop#basic-usage) you will see that you have to return the array like below

```
[
   'out'=>[
       ['id'=>'<city-id>', 'name'=>'<city-name>'],
       ['id'=>'<city-id>', 'name'=>'<city-name>']
    ],
    'selected'=>'<city-id>'
]
```

which means that the id will be provided with the index `id` and the text for the dropdown will be provided with the index `name`, and looking at the response you have provided your method `getAllCities` is returning the array like below

```
 [
    'id'=>'name',
    'id'=>'name',
 ]
```

you didn't add the  method `City::getAllCities($region_id);` which is returning the `$out` array but on the very basic level as per documentation it should look like below,

*Note: Change the `table` and `column` names respectively, I assume you have the `id` and `name` columns for the cities, if you have any other column name for the city name like `city_name` then you must create the alias `name` for the `city_name` field in the query.*

```
public function getAllCities($region_id){

    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    $query->select('id, name')
        ->from('{{%city}}')
        ->where(['=', 'region_id', $region_id])
        ->limit(20);
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    return $command->queryAll();

}
```

This will return an array like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [name] => Велико Търново
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [name] => Горна Оряховица
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42
            [name] => Елена
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 43
            [name] => Златарица
        )

)
```

which will be encoded as JSON like below

```
[
  {
    "id": "40",
    "name": "Велико Търново"
  },
  {
    "id": "41",
    "name": "Горна Оряховица"
  },
  {
    "id": "42",
    "name": "Елена"
  },
  {
    "id": "43",
    "name": "Златарица"
  }
]
```

and eventually when encode by the line

```
echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
```

it will return

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "id": "40",
      "name": "Велико Търново"
    },
    {
      "id": "41",
      "name": "Горна Оряховица"
    },
    {
      "id": "42",
      "name": "Елена"
    },
    {
      "id": "43",
      "name": "Златарица"
    }
  ],
  "selected": ""
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will try it now :) Thank you!

Comment: sure take your time @TomaTomov , i edited a few things just go through the answer again

Comment: Everything fine now. Thank you a lot!